# Android Firebase - constant timeout on writing data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store data in realtime Firebase database.
However even the simplest example from the docs does not work.

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

I enabled debug logs and I've noticed that essentially there is a permanent timeout and retry mechanism trying to connect to Firebase.

```
D/Connection: conn_1 - Opening a connection
D/WebSocket: ws_1 - timed out on connect
D/WebSocket: ws_1 - closed
    ws_1 - closing itself
D/Connection: conn_1 - Realtime connection failed
D/Connection: conn_1 - closing realtime connection
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 964ms
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
D/Connection: conn_2 - Opening a connection
D/WebSocket: ws_2 - timed out on connect
```

It goes on forever and the database table is of course never updated.
I am able to perform a read operation normally.
What can cause this? I'm using regular WiFi. I'm not behind any kind of proxy or VPN.

Comment: It looks like the client can't connect to the server. You might want to try it on a different network, since it seems something along your current route is blocking the connection (either to the specific host, or just web socket traffic in general).

Comment: Thanks, I just tried on my iPhone HotSpot and it worked. This is burdensome but acceptable as it's a small project.

Comment: If you want to make it work on this network, you'll need to figure out where along the way the traffic gets dropped (`tracert` could be your friend there), and then reach out to the sysadmins of that hop to get it addresses.

Comment: Yeah, this could be the way to go. But as this is a regular ISP connection, it could be tricky. As it's only a small and temporary project, HotSpot will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was a network issue. I connected to a HotSpot network and the problem was solved.